# Определение элемента страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как определить элемент открытой страницы, на котором был произведен щелчок мыши?

Comment: Я полагаю как-то так: добавить Listener на событие `click`  и в полученном событии `event.target` и будет элементом по которому произведен клик.

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.textContent);
});
```

```html
<p>One</p>
<p>Two</p>
<p>Three</p>
```